# The method newCompatibleTransport() from the type AndroidHttp refers to the missing type

Tags: java, android

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential
        .usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this,
                Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
credential.setSelectedAccountName(driveAccountName);
//Errors on below line
HttpTransport ht = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(ht, new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
```

> **1. HttpTransport cannot be resolved to a type**
>
> **2. The method newCompatibleTransport() from the type AndroidHttp refers to the missing type HttpTransport**

I have added the following jar files in the libs folder:

> 1. google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar
> 2. google-api-services-drive-v2-rev1-1.7.2-beta.jar
> 3. google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar
> 4. google-http-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Had to use:**

> google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0`. Google has deprecated `http-client` for target versions >= 23